# HTTP Load Time in HTTPWatch compared to Fiddler

Tags: fiddler, httpwatch

In one of my website, there is some issue in Page Load performance. We are judging the performance using Fiddler2 and HTTPwatch 9.4.

In Fiddler, we can see the pageload time is about 4-5 secs. But, if I check in the HTTPWatch then it is showing the HTTPLoad time is 9-10 secs.This comprises DOM Load, Page Load and HTTP Load time.

Can somebody please confirm why there is a difference ?

Comment: Fiddler shows network time only; it doesn't do anything with DOM/JavaScript/etc.

Comment: You should see similar timings in Fiddler and HttpWatch if you look at the network level. Can you add some screen shots to show the data values you are comparing from each tool?